# Minecraft Forge

Tags: command-line, minecraft

When I try to open minecraft forge using the terminal, I keep getting an error that it is unable to access the file.

```
chrx@chrx:~$ java -jar forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-installer.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-installer.jar
```

That's the error.
Please help me! D:

Comment: What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: Are you in the correct directory to access that file? Is this located in the Downloads folder?

Comment: The permissions are Access: Read and Write   Group: chrx   Access: Read only   Others: Read Only               It was on my desktop whilst I was trying to open it.   Am I being stupid???

Comment: You are using the path of your home directory.
If the file is on the Desktop you need to first change your working directory to the Desktop or execute it as follow:
`chrx@chrx:~$ java -jar ~/Desktop/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-installer.jar`